# (Facebook) iPhone and iPad not appearing in App download page

Tags: android, ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

I set up my Application download page on Facebook.

The application runs both on iOS and Android, but, as you can see from the image below, it appears only "Available for Android" and not "Available for iPhone, iPad, Android" as appear on Zombie Tsunami page (for example).

On Facebook Developer, in the "App detail" page, below "App Center Listed Platforms" section, "iOS - iPhone", "iOS - iPad" and "Android" toggle is On, and there are even screenshots for both iPhone and iPad.

What am I doing wrong?

And moreover, Facebook Developer says that "This app is public and available to all users", but if I log on Facebook with a non-developer account, I'm not able to find my own app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you add your mobile platform under `Settings` and provide all the required data under the `App Details` and toggle that platform under `App Center Listed Platforms` you need to **submit your app for review**.

After approval your app center page should get updated (this may take sometime).